# How to pass data from one html page to another?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

These are two html page for a laundry website, one is called the booking page where clients can click to book the number of clothes to be washed and have the total amount to pay, another page called the summary which is suppose to receive data from booking page (no server side language is used, just local storage in JavaScript), but I have not been able to figure it out at all.

I tried using local storage but could not figure it out.

```html
<div class="summaryContainer">
    <div class="summaryNavBar"><p className="summaryTitle">Summary</p> 
</div>
    <div class="summaryContent">
    <p class="total" id="total">Total:</p>
   <p class="sum">&#8358;0.00</p>
    </div>

   <div class="summaryCard">
   <div class="summary-card-title">
       <div>Item</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content">
       <div >Shirt(s)</div><div  id="
   first" class="summary-quantity"><button type="button" id="sub" 
   class="sub">−</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>   </div>
       </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content">

   <div>Trouser(s)</div>
    <div class="summary-quantity" id="second">
   <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content" id="third">
   <div>Suit(s)</div><div class="summary-quantity"><button 
   type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
 <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>   </div>
   </div>

   <p class=" more">..more</p>
   </div>
   <div class="summaryButton">
    <button class="button-left"><span><FontAwesomeIcon 
  class="buttonLeft" icon="angle-left"/></span>Back</button>
  <button class="button-right">Proceed to payment<FontAwesomeIcon 
  class="buttonRight" icon="angle-right"/></button>

    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the Booking page file

```html
  <div class="bookingContainer">
  <div>
      <div class="booking-container-title">
          <p>Book a laundry service</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="first-booking-container">
      <p>What would you like to do ?</p>
      <select>
          <option class="middle">Dry Clean</option>
          <option class="middle">Wash</option>
          <option class="middle">Iron</option>
      </select>
      <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-icon" icon="chevron-down" />
  </div>



  <!-- First Value -->
  <div class="second-booking-container">
      <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
    src="./img/shirt.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
        value="100" id="qnty_1">
              Shirt(s)</p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="first">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
            down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id='firstVal' 
         name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
         </div>

      <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
         src="./img/trouser.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
         value="100" id="qnty_2">
              Trouser(s)</p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="second">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
         down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="secondVal" 
          name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
         </div>

      <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
        src="./img/skirt.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
           value="100" id="qnty_3">
              Skirt(s)</p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="third">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
     down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="thirdVal" 
         name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
      </div>

      <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
           src="./img/blouse.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
           value="100" id="qnty_4">
              Blouse(s)</p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="fourth">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
           down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="fourthVal" 
            name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
      </div>

      <div>
               src="./img/jacket.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon-long" name="product" 
             value="100" id="qnty_5">Suit/Jacket(s)
          </p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="fifth">
              <option>0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
            down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="fifthVal" 
          name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
            </div>
          </div>

  <div class="third-booking-container">
      <p id="total">Total: <span>&#8358;0.00</span></p>
      <button>Set pick up date
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="second-container-button-right" 
       icon="angle-right" /></button>
  </div>
    </div>


  <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Here is the javascript file

```js
  let first = document.querySelector('#first');
  let second = document.querySelector('#second');
  let third = document.querySelector('#third');
  let fourth = document.querySelector('#fourth');
  let fifth = document.querySelector('#fifth');

  //invoke this function when the input changes on individual 
  selected elements
  const totalItem = () => {
   let firstValue = `${first.options[first.selectedIndex].value}`
   let secondValue = `${second.options[second.selectedIndex].value}`
   let thirdValue =
    `${third.options[third.selectedIndex].value}`
   let fourthValue = `${fourth.options[fourth.selectedIndex].value}`
   let fifthValue = `${fifth.options[fifth.selectedIndex].value}`
   console.table(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, fourthValue,
    fifthValue)

   //call function for each cloths and pass 3 values(the selected 
   number, the constant(₦100) and where to update)
  multiplySelectedwithConstVal(firstValue, firstValNo, firstVal);
  multiplySelectedwithConstVal(secondValue, secondValNo,
   secondVal);
  multiplySelectedwithConstVal(thirdValue, thirdValNo, thirdVal);
  multiplySelectedwithConstVal(fourthValue, fourthValNo,
   fourthVal);
  multiplySelectedwithConstVal(fifthValue, fifthValNo, fifthVal);

  //total addition of all values
  let selectedValArray = [];

  const total = () => {
   selectedValArray.push(
    parseInt(firstVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
    parseInt(secondVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
    parseInt(thirdVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
    parseInt(fourthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
    parseInt(fifthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""))
   );
   return selectedValArray.reduce((accu, currentVal) => accu +
    currentVal, 0);
  }
  finalVal.innerHTML = `Total: <span>&#8358;${total()}</span>`
  // console.log(total());

  }

  //target elements that will be updated and
  let firstVal = document.querySelector('#firstVal');
  let secondVal = document.querySelector('#secondVal');
  let thirdVal = document.querySelector('#thirdVal');
  let fourthVal = document.querySelector('#fourthVal');
  let fifthVal = document.querySelector('#fifthVal');
  let finalVal = document.querySelector('#total');

  //convert ₦100 to number for multiplication
  //converted the innerhtml to number
  let firstValNo = parseInt(firstVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
  let secondValNo = parseInt(secondVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
  let thirdValNo = parseInt(thirdVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
  let fourthValNo = parseInt(fourthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
  let fifthValNo = parseInt(fifthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));


  //multiply selected value with constant and update
  const multiplySelectedwithConstVal = (i, k, update) => {
   let result = parseInt(i) * k
   return update.innerHTML = `₦${result}`
  }
```

I want the value gotten from booking page be effected directly into the summary, the plus and minus button should also be able to add or remove the number of clothes and also change the total amount to be paid.

Comment: saving something to localStorage and retrieving it again later looks like this: 
`localStorage.setItem("firstValue", firstValue); let retrievedValue = localStorage.getItem("firstValue"); console.log retrievedValue;`
(See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Hello, please can you help me with the code. Like code it out please and also the plus and minus button should add or remove from the total and also the number of clothes to be washed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This code in your Initial Page i.e Page 1

```
let firstVal = document.querySelector('#firstVal');
let secondVal = document.querySelector('#secondVal');
let thirdVal = document.querySelector('#thirdVal');
let fourthVal = document.querySelector('#fourthVal');
let fifthVal = document.querySelector('#fifthVal');
let finalVal = document.querySelector('#total');


localStorage.setItem("firstVal", firstVal);
localStorage.setItem("secondVal", secondVal);
localStorage.setItem("thirdVal", thirdVal);
localStorage.setItem("fourthVal", fourthVal);
localStorage.setItem("fifthVal", fifthVal);
localStorage.setItem("finalVal", finalVal);
```

Add This code in your Second Page where you want to fetch value i.e Page 2

```
let firstVal = localStorage.getItem(('firstVal');
let secondVal = localStorage.getItem(('secondVal');
let thirdVal = localStorage.getItem(('thirdVal');
let fourthVal = localStorage.getItem(('fourthVal');
let fifthVal = localStorage.getItem(('fifthVal');
let finalVal = localStorage.getItem(('finalVal');

console.log(firstVal);
console.log(secondVal);
console.log(thirdVal);
console.log(fourthVal);
console.log(fifthVal);
console.log(finalVal);
```

you can also learn some basic related to local storage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Here is code for Booking Page where localstorage is used to store the count and item value:

```html
<div class="bookingContainer">
    <div>
       <div class="booking-container-title">
          <p>Book a laundry service</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first-booking-container">
       <p>What would you like to do ?</p>
       <select>
          <option class="middle">Dry Clean</option>
          <option class="middle">Wash</option>
          <option class="middle">Iron</option>
       </select>
       <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-icon" icon="chevron-down" />
    </div>
    <!-- First Value -->
    <div class="second-booking-container">
       <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
             src="./img/shirt.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
             value="100" id="qnty_1">
             Shirt(s)
          </p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="first">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
             down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id='firstVal' 
             name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
             src="./img/trouser.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
             value="100" id="qnty_2">
             Trouser(s)
          </p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="second">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
             down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="secondVal" 
             name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
             src="./img/skirt.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
             value="100" id="qnty_3">
             Skirt(s)
          </p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="third">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
             down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="thirdVal" 
             name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div class="second-booking-container-image"><img 
             src="./img/blouse.png" /></div>
          <p class="second-booking-container-icon" name="product" 
             value="100" id="qnty_4">
             Blouse(s)
          </p>
          <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="fourth">
             <option>0</option>
             <option>1</option>
             <option>2</option>
             <option>3</option>
          </select>
          <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
             down" />
          <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="fourthVal" 
             name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
       </div>
       <div>
          src="./img/jacket.png" />
       </div>
       <p class="second-booking-container-icon-long" name="product" 
          value="100" id="qnty_5">Suit/Jacket(s)
       </p>
       <select onchange='totalItem()' class="center" id="fifth">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
       </select>
       <FontAwesomeIcon class="select-long-icon" icon="chevron- 
          down" />
       <p class="second-booking-container-text" id="fifthVal" 
          name="price" max="3" min="1">&#8358;100</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="third-booking-container">
    <p id="total">Total: <span>&#8358;0.00</span></p>
    <button>
       Set pick up date
       <FontAwesomeIcon class="second-container-button-right" 
          icon="angle-right" />
    </button>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script>
    let first = document.querySelector('#first');
    let second = document.querySelector('#second');
    let third = document.querySelector('#third');
    let fourth = document.querySelector('#fourth');
    let fifth = document.querySelector('#fifth');
    //invoke this function when the input changes on individual 
    // selected elements
    const totalItem = () => {

        let firstValue = `${first.options[first.selectedIndex].value}`
        let secondValue = `${second.options[second.selectedIndex].value}`
        let thirdValue =
            `${third.options[third.selectedIndex].value}`
        let fourthValue = `${fourth.options[fourth.selectedIndex].value}`
        let fifthValue = `${fifth.options[fifth.selectedIndex].value}`
        console.table(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, fourthValue,
            fifthValue)
        
        //call function for each cloths and pass 3 values(the selected 
        // number, the constant(₦100) and where to update)
        multiplySelectedwithConstVal(firstValue, firstValNo, firstVal);
        multiplySelectedwithConstVal(secondValue, secondValNo,
        secondVal);
        multiplySelectedwithConstVal(thirdValue, thirdValNo, thirdVal);
        multiplySelectedwithConstVal(fourthValue, fourthValNo,
        fourthVal);
        multiplySelectedwithConstVal(fifthValue, fifthValNo, fifthVal);

        //total addition of all values
        let selectedValArray = [];
        
        const total = () => {
            selectedValArray.push(
                parseInt(firstVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
                parseInt(secondVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
                parseInt(thirdVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
                parseInt(fourthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", "")),
                parseInt(fifthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""))
            );
            return selectedValArray.reduce((accu, currentVal) => accu +
                currentVal, 0);
        }
        var totalval = total();

        finalVal.innerHTML = `Total: <span>&#8358;${totalval}</span>`;
        localStorage.clear();  
        localStorage.setItem("firstVal",firstValNo);
        localStorage.setItem("secondVal", secondValNo);
        localStorage.setItem("thirdVal", thirdValNo);
        localStorage.setItem("fourthVal",  fourthValNo);
        localStorage.setItem("fifthVal",  fifthValNo);
        localStorage.setItem("firstValCount", firstValue);
        localStorage.setItem("secondValCount", secondValue);
        localStorage.setItem("thirdValCount",  thirdValue);
        localStorage.setItem("fourthValCount", fourthValue);
        localStorage.setItem("fifthValCount",  fifthValue);
        localStorage.setItem("finalVal", totalval);
    }

    
    //target elements that will be updated and
    let firstVal = document.querySelector('#firstVal');
    let secondVal = document.querySelector('#secondVal');
    let thirdVal = document.querySelector('#thirdVal');
    let fourthVal = document.querySelector('#fourthVal');
    let fifthVal = document.querySelector('#fifthVal');
    let finalVal = document.querySelector('#total');

    //convert ₦100 to number for multiplication
    //converted the innerhtml to number
    let firstValNo = parseInt(firstVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
    let secondValNo = parseInt(secondVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
    let thirdValNo = parseInt(thirdVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
    let fourthValNo = parseInt(fourthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
    let fifthValNo = parseInt(fifthVal.innerHTML.replace("₦", ""));
    
    //multiply selected value with constant and update
    const multiplySelectedwithConstVal = (i, k, update) => {
        let result = parseInt(i) * k
        return update.innerHTML = `₦${result}`
    }
 </script>
```

Here is code for Summary page with add/ substract logic

```html
<div class="summaryContainer">
    <div class="summaryNavBar"><p className="summaryTitle">Summary</p> 
</div>
    <div class="summaryContent">
    <p class="total" id="total">Total:</p>
    </div>

   <div class="summaryCard">
   <div class="summary-card-title">
       <div>Item</div>
      <div>Quantity</div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content">
       <div >Shirt(s)</div><div  id="
   first" class="summary-quantity"><button type="button" id="sub" 
   class="sub">−</button>
    <input type="text" id="firstVal" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>   </div>
       </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content">

   <div>Trouser(s)</div>
    <div class="summary-quantity" id="second">
   <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
    <input type="text" id="secondVal" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary-card-content" id="third">
   <div>Suit(s)</div><div class="summary-quantity"><button 
   type="button" id="sub" class="sub">−</button>
 <input type="text" id="thirdVal" value="0" class="field" />
      <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>   </div>
   </div>

   <p class=" more">..more</p>
   </div>
   <div class="summaryButton">
    <button class="button-left"><span><FontAwesomeIcon 
  class="buttonLeft" icon="angle-left"/></span>Back</button>
  <button class="button-right">Proceed to payment<FontAwesomeIcon 
  class="buttonRight" icon="angle-right"/></button>

    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>



<script>

var firstValue = localStorage.getItem('firstVal');
var secondValue = localStorage.getItem('secondVal');
var thirdValue = localStorage.getItem('thirdVal');
var finalValue = localStorage.getItem('finalVal');


var firstValueCount = localStorage.getItem('firstValCount');
var secondValueCount = localStorage.getItem('secondValCount');
var thirdValueCount = localStorage.getItem('thirdValCount');


var finalVal = document.querySelector('#total');

finalVal.innerHTML = `Total: <span>&#8358;${finalValue}</span>`;
document.getElementById('firstVal').value = firstValueCount ;
document.getElementById('secondVal').value = secondValueCount ;
document.getElementById('thirdVal').value = thirdValueCount ;
var first = document.querySelector('#first');
var second = document.querySelector('#second');
var third = document.querySelector('#third');
var fourth = document.querySelector('#fourth');
var fifth = document.querySelector('#fifth');
//invoke this function when the input changes on individual 
// selected elements
function calSum(el ,type){

  
    if(type == "add"){
      var id = (el.previousSibling.previousElementSibling.id);
      var count = parseInt(el.previousSibling.previousElementSibling.value);
      // increment count by one 
      var final_count =   (count + 1);
      el.previousSibling.previousElementSibling.value = final_count;

    }else{
      var id = (el.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.id);
      var count = parseInt(el.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.value);
      // decrement count by one 
      var final_count =   (count - 1);
      el.nextSibling.nextElementSibling.value = final_count;
    }
    var totalSum = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('finalVal'));
    var price = 100;
    if(id === 'firstVal'){   
        totalSum = (totalSum + (price  * final_count)) -(count *price) ;    
        localStorage.setItem("firstValCount", final_count);
        
    }else if(id === 'secondVal'){
        totalSum =  (totalSum + (price  * final_count)) -(count *price);
        localStorage.setItem("secondValCount", final_count);

    }else if(id === 'thirdVal'){
        totalSum = (totalSum + (price  * final_count)) -(count *price) ;    
        localStorage.setItem("thirdValCount", final_count);

    }   
    console.log(totalSum);
    localStorage.setItem("finalVal", totalSum);
    document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = `Total: <span>&#8358;${totalSum}</span>`;
}


  var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("add");

  for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
      
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      calSum(this,'add');
    } , false);
  }

  var sub = document.getElementsByClassName("sub");

  for (var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
      
    sub[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      calSum(this,'sub');
    } , false);
  }


</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked but the plus and minus button still doesn't work. It should be able to add and subtract the number of clothes picked and also the amount to be paid in total.

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother you but can you help me add the code. Need to submit this work in 3hours time please. Thank you

Comment: Somebody help, I haven't figured this out please.

Comment: hi @Emmanuel i have updated add/substract logic have a look and mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Hello @rishab, still having issues with this. Its still not work. Can i share the codepen link for both and you help me take a look

Comment: and here is the summary page link too https://codepen.io/delaquash/pen/eqdLaa.   Kindly help me figure it out, I have to submit this tomorrow and present on wednesday final bootcamp demo day

Comment: Did you refreshed the summary page after selecting item from booking page! and also codepen will not set value in localstorage, Also your HTML is different i have made changes in textbox id